# Building your own PC computer, is there a process checklist?

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, troubleshooting

I have just built a new pc. I installed all the components and checked all cable connections. But when I turned it on the first time it did nothing, except the fans ran and several leds lit up. There was no video output and no beeps. Does anyone have a trusty checklist or troubleshooting guide that can help me figure out what is wrong?
Thanks

The system components include:
1 x Corsair Hydro Series™ H100i V2 Extreme Performance Water / Liquid CPU Cooler. 240mm

1 x ASRock Z170 Extreme7+ LGA 1151 Intel Z170 HDMI/DVI/Display Port SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard

1 x CORSAIR CX series CX750M 750W ATX12V v2.3 80 PLUS BRONZE Certified Modular Active PFC Power Supply

2 x Pioneer Black Blu-ray Burner SATA BDR-209DBK

1 x Corsair Carbide Series 100R CC-9011075-WW Black Steel ATX Mid Tower Computer Case ATX

1 x Intel Core i7-6700K 8M Skylake Quad-Core 4.0 GHz LGA 1151 91W BX80662I76700K Desktop Processor Intel® HD Graphics ...

1 x Crucial MX200 M.2 Type 2260DS (Double Sided) 500GB SATA 6Gbps (SATA III) Micron 16nm MLC NAND Internal Solid State ...
Form Factor: M.2 / Capacity: 500GB

```
Crucial 32gb memory 2x16
```

Comment: Normally no beeps is memory/cpu  Make sure they are seated right.  Does the CPU fan spin?

Comment: is the cpu connector in?

Comment: Normally no beeps is a motherboard without an internal speaker installed :P

Comment: Does Dr. Debug light up?  If so, the code can help you with troubleshooting.  If not, and you've reset the CMOS, then probably part of the board isn't getting power.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try a few things.

1. Disconnect everything
2. Set a *minimal* system - one stick of ram, no optical drive, power. Doublecheck to ensure CPU power's plugged in. A lot of people forget.
3. If it dosen't work, note down and check up the leds - many systems use those to indicate faults over beeps.

Comments indicate asrocks have a [debug code system](http://www.asrock.com/support/faq.asp?id=334) (I'm assuming its those little 8 segment displays) which may be of use as well.

4. if it does, add components one at a time till failure.

Comment: starting from a minimal setup is the way to go here.